# java android view structure

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, object-oriented-analysis

Just a simple maybe stupid question.
Is it ok to use multiple activities at once in an android application using an Inflater? I want to have multiple views on my screen without losing the previous view. For example, a user clicks on a button and a information screen shows up. Start Intent would convert the whole screen to the information screen activity.

Using an Inflater works but I'm just wondering if its the right way to display multiple views. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read up on Fragments?

Comment: @TanjaV, you should post an answer so that Mark can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Fragments for this. Each fragment has a view/layout and you can move them in & out of your main view as you require. There are many tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of the views, e.g.:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: So you would recommend to use just one xml file? 
I also have a lot of dynamic content so a 'static' xml with all the components declared in it isnt an option.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. TanjaV is probably right in suggesting the use of Fragments, but i find hard to see what is your goal.

Comment: No problem. The Fragments are exactly what i meant. Remember reading this earlier but didn't really made any sense since I was used working with Objective-C and having multiple subclasses of Views.
Beginning to understand the concept of Java in Android.